# Exploring the damping of a vertical spring-mass system

Tags: homework-and-exercises, resource-recommendations, harmonic-oscillator, spring

I am planning to write a small paper about the damping of a vertical spring-mass system. I want to explore a few interesting factors affecting the damping.

Right now, I thought about making the mass move through 2 mediums in one oscillation, and explore the affect of change in viscocity.

I would be grateful if someone could suggest any other interesting factors/ changes I could investigate through my experiments.

Comment: Are you planning on simulating the oscillator numerically, or are you going to  derive all of your results analytically? This would have an impact on what questions you might want to ask.

Comment: @MaxwellAifer Both are fine. It would be great it if I can carry out the practical experiment. But, if needed, I will make a simulation.